# handlebar template input box with datepicker, initial value set in html doesn't remain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, handlebars.js

I have a handlebar based html template, in which a date box is showing up the date.

```
<input type="text" value="{{this.starting}}" name="management-rules-starting"/><br/>
```

Then I have implemented the datepicker on top of this box

```
$('input[name=management-rules-starting]').datepicker();
$('input[name=management-rules-starting]').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
```

The date picker shows up but the initial value set in the html by the value {{this.starting}} doesn't remain.
I am also quite sure that the initial value set is in the proper yyyy-mm-dd format, like 2014-03-21

Comment: I think the problem is with `{{this.starting}}` instead try directly without `{{starting}}`.  I'm not sure but once I too face a same issue like `{{obj.starting}} //DIDN'T WORK` later I parsed and simply did set `{{starting}} //WORKED`.

Comment: The value comes in the textbox if i don't plug the datepicker with it, the moment i plug the datepicker the initial value doesn't show up, but when i select a date by datepicker, that date shows up.